# populate data on datatable does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I would like to populate my data on a datatable which is plotted on a modal, I searched a lot of link and I came across one interesting topic..

I have a button that will trigger the function to get the data from the servlet..

```
<button class="w3-btn w3-black w3-round-xxlarge w3-hover-green" id="viewButton" onClick="loadDoc(this.id)">View</button>
```

my ajax code..

```
<script>
function loadDoc(id) {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      openModal(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "/ETEEAP/ViewApplication?id=" + id, true);
  xhttp.send();
}
function openModal(id){
document.getElementById('id01').style.display='block';
loadTable(id);
}   
</script>
```

I was able to open the modal but it returns an error "REQUESTED UNKNOWN"
http://datatables.net/tn/4 for details of the error..

this is my modal codes..

```
<div id="id01" class="w3-modal">
<div class="w3-modal-content w3-animate-top w3-card-8" style="margin-top:20px;">
<header class="w3-container w3-teal">
  <span onclick="document.getElementById('id01').style.display='none';"
  class="w3-closebtn">&times;</span>
  <h2>Program Details</h2>
</header>
<div class="w3-container w3-light-grey" style="margin-bottom: 50px;">
  <div class="w3-container w3-padding-8 w3-opacity w3-white w3-round-xlarge w3-border w3-hover-border-black"
    style="margin: 10px 10px 10px 10px;">
        <table id="myTable1" class="display">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>SUBJECT</th>
            <th>COURSE</th>
            <th>UNITS</th>
            <th>SEMESTER</th>
            <th>YEAR LEVEL</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>SUBJECT</th>
            <th>COURSE</th>
            <th>UNITS</th>
            <th>SEMESTER</th>
            <th>YEAR LEVEL</th>
            <th>STATUS</th>
        </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    <script>
        function loadTable(id){
            alert(id);
            $('#myTable1').DataTable({
                aaData : id,
                aoColumns : [
                    {mDataProp : "SUBJECT"},
                    {mDataProp : "COURSE"},
                    {mDataProp : "UNITS"},
                    {mDataProp : "SEMESTER"},
                    {mDataProp : "YEAR LEVEL"},
                    {mDataProp : "STATUS"}
                            ]
             });
        }
    </script>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the response I get from the servlet..

```
 [{"SUBJECT":"Programming I","UNITS":"3","SEMESTER":"First","COURSE":"BSCPE","YEAR LEVEL":"First","STATUS":"PENDING"}, {"SUBJECT":"Communication Arts I","UNITS":"2","SEMESTER":"First","COURSE":"BSCPE","YEAR LEVEL":"First","STATUS":"PENDING"}, {"SUBJECT":"Programming II","UNITS":"3","SEMESTER":"Second","COURSE":"BSCPE","YEAR LEVEL":"First","STATUS":"PENDING"}, {"SUBJECT":"COMORG","UNITS":"4","SEMESTER":"Second","COURSE":"BSCPE","YEAR LEVEL":"Second","STATUS":"PENDING"}]
```

when I run this program it throws the error above.. but when I assign and hardcode the specified response on a variable it works fine.. how come is it not working? can anyone help me..

Comment: Could you post the `loadTable` function, too?

Comment: its on the modal code.. :D

Comment: Your response from servlet is string or JSON object?

Comment: the response is json

Answer (score 1):

It is now working.. I only converted the response to json..

id = $.parseJSON(id);